# What is the difference between Munich and CaraMunich malts?

Tags: beer, malt

I know there are different versions of each, like Light or Dark, I II III. I'd like to have the general differences between the two, mainly!

Thanks!

Comment: I'm convinced that the recipes that I've seen around the web calling for "1/2lb Munich" as a specialty grain, were actually mistranslated somewhere along the way and originally referred to CaraMunich.

Comment: Maybe, but I wouldn't be so sure.  There are a lot of homebrewers who think that adding 1/2 lb. of Munich will make more difference than it actually does.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The "cara" in CaraMunich indicates that it's a crystal malt.  It's essentially "mashed" in the husk, then kilned to produce sugar and a glassy kernel, like other crystal malts.  Munich malt does not go through that process.  It's a relatively dark kilned malt than can be used as a base malt.  Their flavors and uses are very different. Munich can be combined with other base malts or used as 100% of your grist if you like.  CaraMunich, on the other hand, has a much sweeter flavor and should always be used as a "character" malt in relatively small quantities (generally less that 10%) of your total grist.

Comment: Thanks a lot. As a side-question, will the different kinds (Light, Dark, I, II, III, etc...) taste differently, or if it is mainly just a question of color?

Comment: No, they do taste differently.  The darker the color, the more toasty the flavor for the Munich. The caraMunich also does that, but the taste gets more toffee/caramel like as it gets darker.